# A sort of "Taylor expansion" of a power series

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, taylor-expansion

I have the following question. Suppose $$f(x):=\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}c_ix^i$$ is a power series that converges for $|x|<1 + \epsilon$, for some $\epsilon >0$, where $x\in\mathbb{C}$. I can then define the sequence $$g_i:=\sum_{j=i+1}^{\infty}c_j,$$ which is well defined by the assumed convergence of $f$ at 1. Now here is (the first part of) my question: How do I see (better: prove rigorously) that $$h(x):= \sum_{i=0}^{\infty}g_ix^i$$ also converges (at least) for $|x|<1 + \epsilon$? What I am ultimately interested in is establishing an "expansion" of $f$ around 0, i.e., $$f(x) = f(1) + (x-1) \sum_{i=0}^{\infty}g_ix^i, \quad \forall |x|<1+\epsilon. $$ How would I go about proving such an identity?

Many thanks for any help, I very much appreciate it!

Comment: I guess there should be $g_i:=\sum_{j=i+1}^{\infty}c_j$. You have $c_i$ there.

Comment: The basic idea on these proofs is: comparison to geometric series.

Comment: thanks for the comments (I have corrected the "$j$" typo, thanks for spotting that). how would I do the comparison with the geometric series (I am having trouble with that), especially for $1 < \abs{x} < 1+\epsilon$? thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First I redefine $g_i:=\sum_{j=i}^{\infty}c_j$. Because it makes formulas easier and idea won't change.

Than you can write $h(x)= \sum_{i=0}^{\infty}c_i \sum_{j=0}^i x^j$. Because $\sum_{i=0}^{\infty} \sum_{j=i}^\infty |c_j x^i|<\infty$, we'll see this later.

Now using formula for sum of geometric series you get $$\sum_{i=0}^{\infty} \sum_{j=i}^\infty |c_j x^i|=\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}|c_i| \sum_{j=0}^i |x|^j = \sum_{i=0}^{\infty}|c_i| \frac{1-|x|^{i+1}}{1-|x|} = \frac{1}{1-|x|}(\sum_{i=0}^\infty |c_i| - |x|\sum_{i=0}^\infty |c_i| |x^i|)<\infty$$ for $|x|<1+\epsilon$ and $x\neq 1$. For case $x=1$ you have to do it separately (you have to show that $\sum_{i=0}^\infty c_i i <\infty$)

So now you can write $h(x) = \frac{1}{1-x}(f(1) - xf(x))$. Therefore $f(x) = \frac{1}{x}(f(1) +(x-1)h(x))$

Comment: I think it should be $\sum_{j=0}^{i-1}$ in your second term of your geometric series computation.